# Splash screen default bar style for iOS 13 and light content for pre 13

Tags: ios, splash-screen, ios13, uistatusbar, ios-darkmode

I want to achieve the following:

- Light content status bar on **splash screen** when iOS version is < 13
- Default status bar on **splash screen** when iOS version is 13 (light content when dark mode and dark content when light mode)

These are the options I tried:

- Setting info.plist bar style to Light Content - caused iOS 13 light mode to show the light content bar style.
- Setting info.plist bar style to Default - caused iOS <13 to show the dark content bar style.
- Changing the Interface Style of the splash screen to Dark so that iOS <13 will use the light content bar style.

Comment: Hey did you ever figure this out?